# Google Play Store is showing "top developer" sign randomly and wrong. Why?

Tags: google-play-store, malware

I was trying to search for podcast apps. When the apps are listed, some of them have "top developer" sign (blue diamond), and when I select one app and go into it and come back to search results again, the "top developer" signs changes to some other apps.

For example, look at the following snapshots:

[image: All are trusted]

<sup>All apps are from top developers (click the image for full size)</sup>

[image: Some are not trusted]

<sup>Some of previous apps are actually not from top developers (click the image for full size)</sup>

Is this a bug or is my OS affected like in Mr. Robot?

Comment: I clarified that's not "trusted app", but ["top developer" icon](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about.html#featured-staff-picks). Does this always happen on the first search?

Comment: I found it since yesterday..I can't say if it always happens